# PHP/MySQL: importing CSV, all date and decimal value are null, zero

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

I am having problems importing CSV data into MySQL via PHP. All imported date and decimal values (anything not varchar or INT) show up in MySQL as 0 or 0000-00-00 (null?). The PHP handling of the CSV returns correct values when I echo them out, and I am getting no `mysqli_error()`, so I believe this is a MySQL issue.

Here is my data table configuration
[image: Table: bccounts]

[image: Table: monthly_balances]

I can provide code if needed

**EDIT**

The CSV is delineated by "|"

`while(($fileop = fgetcsv($handle,1000,"|")) !== false) { //code`

The CSV file

```
account_name|account_cycle|bal_date|bal_month_sales|bal_month_returns|bal_month_net|bal_YTD_sales|bal_YTD_returns|bal_YTD_net|bal_lastyear_sales|bal_lastyear_returns|bal_lastyear_net|||
Jeweler 1|5/22/2013|3/31/2014|$306.00|$0.00|$306.00|$306.00|$0.00|$306.00|$404.00|$0.00|$404.00|||
Jeweler 2|5/12/2012|3/31/2014|$70.00|$0.00|$70.00|$178.00|$0.00|$178.00|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|||
Jeweler 3|1/1/2012|3/31/2014|$52.00|$0.00|$52.00|$9,109.50|$0.00|$9,109.50|$895.20|$0.00|$895.20|||
Jeweler 4|3/16/2012|3/31/2014|$18.60|$0.00|$18.60|$575.80|$0.00|$575.80|$1,982.80|-$68.02|$1,914.78|||
Jeweler 5|2/5/2011|3/31/2014|$292.00|$0.00|$292.00|$2,725.95|-$596.98|$2,128.97|$323.00|$0.00|$323.00|||
Jeweler 6|7/4/2012|3/31/2014|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|$2,463.00|-$1,108.69|$1,354.31|$2,324.90|-$996.50|$1,328.40|||
Jeweler 7|9/26/2013|3/31/2014|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|$2,553.00|-$1,206.02|$1,346.98|||
Jeweler 8|3/28/2011|3/31/2014|$168.00|$0.00|$168.00|$334.00|$0.00|$334.00|$564.00|$0.00|$564.00|||
Jeweler 9|3/1/2011|3/31/2014|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|$1,400.00|$0.00|$1,400.00|$3,332.00|-$637.82|$2,694.18|||
Jeweler 10|12/15/2011|3/31/2014|$428.00|$0.00|$428.00|$1,198.75|$0.00|$1,198.75|$36.00|$0.00|$36.00|||
Jeweler 11|12/1/2012|3/31/2014|$312.00|$0.00|$312.00|$1,504.00|$0.00|$1,504.00|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|||
Jeweler 12|6/5/2013|3/31/2014|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|-$981.54|-$981.54|$1,818.11|$0.00|$1,818.11|||
Jeweler 13|5/23/2013|3/31/2014|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|||
Jeweler 14|8/31/2012|3/31/2014|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|$142.00|$0.00|$142.00|$396.95|$0.00|$396.95|||
Jeweler 15|4/14/2013|3/31/2014|$2,657.80|$0.00|$2,657.80|$2,745.80|$0.00|$2,745.80|$672.80|$0.00|$672.80|||
Jeweler 16|8/22/2012|3/31/2014|$2,292.80|$0.00|$2,292.80|$2,708.80|$0.00|$2,708.80|$8,219.75|$0.00|$8,219.75|||
Jeweler 17|11/11/2010|3/31/2014|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|||
Jeweler 18|1/31/2012|3/31/2014|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|$2,330.00|$0.00|$2,330.00|$3,093.42|$0.00|$3,093.42|||
Jeweler 19|2/1/2011|3/31/2014|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|$60.00|$0.00|$60.00|$144.00|$0.00|$144.00|||
Jeweler 20|7/16/2013|3/31/2014|$58.00|-$30.40|$27.60|$2,757.40|-$979.26|$1,778.14|$1,953.60|$0.00|$1,953.60|||
Jeweler 21|9/28/2012|3/31/2014|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|||
Jeweler 22|10/11/2012|3/31/2014|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|$108.00|$0.00|$108.00|||
Jeweler 23|5/3/2010|3/31/2014|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|||
Jeweler 24|7/23/2012|3/31/2014|$118.00|$0.00|$118.00|$246.00|$0.00|$246.00|$0.00|$0.00|$0.00|||
```

Comment: maybe the csv is storing these fields as strings. can you give a sample row from the csv

Comment: How are you attempting to import the CSV?

Comment: oohhh dam forgot to take out the dollars, had that on the agenda

Comment: its the dollar signs.

Comment: it's not just that. The content types don't match their expected formats. Are you sure date data types can accept m/d/Y import format? I think it will only accept Y-m-d, but I could be wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

needed to take out "$" from the csv

however, date values are still 0000-00-00, reckon I'll have to do some format changing with that

**EDIT**
used `date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $originalDate)));` to fix date formatting

Answer (score -1):

Your date format is wrong, use Y-m-d instead (2001-11-00)